# Where can one find a specification for the data structures representing a dll in memory?

Tags: memory, dll, structure

Specifically I want to know what the data structure for the imports (idata) section looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL file format is the same as that of EXE files, the PE (portable executable) format. You can get [a copy of the specification](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx) from Microsoft. You can also try [Wotsit](http://www.wotsit.org/) for general file-format information.

Windows provides the [ImageHlp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680181.aspx) API for working with executable files. The [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680209.aspx) function looks like a good place to start.

You should also take a look at [the "Portable Executable File Format" chapter](http://www.windowsitlibrary.com/Content/356/11/1.html) of *Undocumented Windows NT*. It seems to describe how to use ImageHlp to get at various parts of a binary. I think the part you're most interested in is on the fourth page, which describes the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` part of the PE file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. 

I've looked at this spec but it definitely seemed as though the on disc structure differed from that in memory (though I may be mistaken). You can definitely see that the idata section contains two lists - one of function ptrs and one of function names.

Comment: Read the links I gave you, especially Undocumented Windows. It explains how ImageHlp will help you do the disk-to-memory mappings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was mistaken - the structure of the PE file seems to be identical in memory.

One can use the structures defined in [winnt.h](http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/winnt.h.html) to interpret the memory.

When looking at these structures, you have to remember that the offsets (or 'RVA's[1]) are *little endian*. I probably wouldn't have been as confused if I just pointed a program at the relevant memory rather than using a debugger.

[1] In microsoft speak.